# Create sub-type instances in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, navigation-properties, subtype, createobject

I am developing an ASP.NET Core application. There are several entities, some of which have one-to-many relations with each other i.e.

Project 1->* Priority, Project 1->* Milestone; Milestone 1->* Issue...

All navigation properties of all entities are virtual and I have already configured lazy loading in OnConfiguring method in the DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
```

The situation is following: I have already created an instance or Project type and now I want to create instances of other sub-types which should be related to the already created Project instance.

My logic for creating of Priority instance is to pass a projectId to the priority entity which will be added  to the corresponding DbSet.

The entity models:

```
public class Project
{
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

The priorityInputModel from the form:

```
public class PriorityInputModel : IMapTo<PriorityServiceModel>
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    }
```

The PriorityServiceModel:

```
public class PriorityServiceModel : IMapFrom<Priority>, IMapTo<Priority>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        public ProjectServiceModel Project { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PriorityInputModel inputModel)
{
    var priorityServiceModel = inputModel.To<PriorityServiceModel>();
    var priorityServiceModelResult = await this.priorityService.CreateAsync(priorityServiceModel);

    return this.RedirectToRoute(
                routeName: ValuesConstants.DefaultRouteName,
                routeValues: new
                {
                    controller = ValuesConstants.ProjectControllerName,
                    action = ValuesConstants.DetailsActionName,
                    id = priorityServiceModelResult.ProjectId,
                });
        }
```

The service method:

```
public async Task<PriorityServiceModel> CreateAsync(PriorityServiceModel priorityServiceModel)
        {
            var priority = priorityServiceModel.To<Priority>();
            var priorityResult = await this.repository.AddAsync(priority);
            var priorityServiceModelResult = priorityResult.To<PriorityServiceModel>();

            return priorityServiceModelResult;
        }
```

The repository method:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            await this.DbSet.AddAsync(entity);
            await this.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity;
        }
```

I expected when the changes had been saved, the returned Priority object to have initialized Project navigation property with the corresponding project instance but the returned object has value as follows:

```
Priority {
    "Id" = 33,
    "Name" = "Lowest",
    "ProjectId" = "bd15bd0c-fed7-4186-ade0-ad9338dff1d7"
    "Project" = null
}
```

What is the reason for this and how could I receive the project instance initialized in the navigation property Project of newly created and returned Priority object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us the code you have for getting data from the database.

Comment: @DavidG , I have added the rest part of the code.